# Magento2: Issue listing products

Tags: magento2

I do not know why, but when I now enter any category, it displays all products from the category. I have set limit listing 24 product to page but dispaly all products from category.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have u changes the per page value at store view label ?

Comment: I checked everything  And everywhere is use the basic configuration

Comment: I have try to optimize magento as here https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003450474-How-to-speed-up-your-Magento-2-store-and-increase-performance-

Comment: I made points 2 and 3 and after deploy system  I have this issue, I restored everything as it was originally but it remained. Can it have something to do with it?

Comment: i donot think optimize  is create any issue. Have u check per page product collection at store view level?https://ibb.co/d9wP9z

Comment: Amit, yes I have checked every page and is set limit 24. By the way, I deploy system again and I see our page she was very narrow. I do not know why https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/

Comment: Your system has a infinite scroll extension which is showing all product  using ajax.Using the extension like https://amasty.com/infinite-scroll-for-magento-2.html

Comment: thanks for your help, but before it was ok without any extension?